# Solving logical formula with own data type and a map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a logical formulae solving program in Haskell. So far I've managed to print given formula as string, for example formula

```
(I (N (Z 'p')) (A (C (Z 'p') (Z 'q')) (Z 'r')))
```

results in

```
"(~p => ((p & q) | r))"
```

*where I is implication, A is alternative, C in conjunction, N in negation and Z is character.*

My data type is like:

```
data Formula = Z Char | V Bool | N Formula 
               | K Formula Formula | A Formula Formula 
               | C Formula Formula | Join Formula Formula
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write a function, which will evaluate formula with given map of characters and boolean values, I mean, for ex.:
    [('p', True), ('q', False), ('r', False)]
I can't come up with a method to substitute those letters with some True/False value and check it. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just pass the list of character and boolean values and use the [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3alookup) function from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

evaluate :: [(Char, Bool)] -> Formula -> Bool
evaluate mapping (Z sym) =
    case lookup sym mapping of
       Just v -> v
       Nothing -> error $ "Undefined symbol " ++ show v
evaluate _mapping (V v) = v
evaluate mapping (N formula) = not (evaluate mapping formula)
...
```

For a more efficient representation of the mapping, use the [`Data.Map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html) module instead of the list of associations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an interpreter.  This sounds scary, but Haskell actually makes it easy.  You can make one like:

```
eval :: [(Char, Bool)] -> Formula -> Maybe Bool
eval vars (Z c) = lookup c vars
eval vars (V b) = Just b
eval vars (N expr) = fmap not $ eval vars expr
eval vars (A e1 e2) = liftM2 (||) (eval vars e1) (eval vars e2)
```

And just finish filling out the rest of the definitions for the different constructors in this style.

As Ganesh points out, you can also use the `Data.Map` module for a more efficient lookup, but the general concept remains.  If you wanted it to look nice and pretty, you could also define a few operators like

```
(<||>) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
(<||>) = liftM2 (||)

(<&&>) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
(<&&>) = liftM2 (&&)

eval :: ...
-- ...
eval vars (A e1 e2) = eval vars e1 <||> eval vars e2
eval vars (C e1 e2) = eval vars e1 <&&> eval vars e2
```

And then your code will be very readable.  Conveniently, these operators can be used in other situations, such as:

```
isABCD :: Char -> Bool
isABCD = (== 'A') <||> (== 'B') <||> (== 'C') <||> (== 'D')
```

Obviously, this is a very contrived example, but it has its uses